# How can I find out which OS I am running in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there an Elisp command which can return "Mac", "Windows", "linux", etc??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

system-type is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is gnu/linux

Documentation:
The value is a symbol indicating the type of operating system you are using.
Special values:

```
  `gnu'          compiled for a GNU Hurd system.
  `gnu/linux'    compiled for a GNU/Linux system.
  `gnu/kfreebsd' compiled for a GNU system with a FreeBSD kernel.
  `darwin'       compiled for Darwin (GNU-Darwin, Mac OS X, ...).
  `ms-dos'       compiled as an MS-DOS application.
  `windows-nt'   compiled as a native W32 application.
  `cygwin'       compiled using the Cygwin library.
```

Anything else (in Emacs 23.1, the possibilities are: aix, berkeley-unix,
hpux, irix, lynxos 3.0.1, usg-unix-v) indicates some sort of Unix system.

Comment: What about 64 bit windows? Is that covered by windows-nt (contrary to what the description says)? Or is it not possible to compile emacs for 64 bit Windows (hard to imagine)? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe you can see a difference in the system-configuration variable, but I can't check. Official standpoint on system-type is "we really really don't want to add new values". Most likely, nobody can be bothered to compile it win/64.